# HBase Shell command questions

Tags: nosql, hbase, hbase-shell

I have some questions about HBase Shell Command Tool:

```
1: How to list all column family names (just names!) in a table?
2: How to count the number of rows in a column family?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1: How to list all column family names (just names!) in a table?**

Not possible OOTB. But you could do something like this :

```
echo "scan 'table'" | bin/hbase shell | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
```

**2: How to count the number of rows in a column family?**

What do you mean by this? Do you intend to ask How to count the number of column families in a rows? If this is what you need, try this :

```
echo "scan 'table'" | bin/hbase shell | grep cf | wc -l
```

Comment: For Q2: I want to count How many rows a column family contained

Answer (score 1):

I have a listColumns script based on Tariq's answer that limits the scan (because I'd like it to finish in my lifetime).

```
echo "scan '$1', LIMIT => 1" | hbase shell | awk '{print $2}' | grep column | sort | uniq | awk -F = '{print $2} '
```

Obviously you run the risk of rows having different columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `describe`, it will show the column families as `NAME=> 'columnfamilyname'`